# Volume using double integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

> Calculate the volume of the solid bounded by the following surfaces:
>   $y=x^2, y=1, x+y+z=4, z=0$.

How does on set up the integral?

Comment: $y = x^2$ is a *plane*??

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Sorry, that was a mistranslation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y=x^2$ is "parabola shifted infinitely" accordingly z-axis.

Your volume can be calculate by 2 and/or 3 dimensional integral:

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{x^2}^{1}\int_{0}^{4-x-y}dxdydz= \int_{-1}^{1}\int_{x^2}^{1}(4-x-y)dxdy$$
Hope, you can finish it.